# jOOQ like any, ignore case

Tags: postgresql, sql-like, jooq

So from https://blog.jooq.org/quantified-like-any-predicates-in-jooq-3-12/ I was expecting this to work:

```kotlin
private fun Condition.andProjectIn(projects: Collection<String>): Condition = when {
    projects.isNotEmpty() -> this.and(FOO.PROJECT_NAME.likeIgnoreCase(any(projects.toTypedArray())))
    else -> this
}
```

(where `PROJECT_NAME` is a `TableField<FooRecord, String>` )

but what I'm getting, instead, is

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
        likeIgnoreCase(String!) defined in org.jooq.TableField
        likeIgnoreCase(Field<String!>!) defined in org.jooq.TableField
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're seeing those errors is because there's no such overload accepting a [`QuantifiedSelect`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/QuantifiedSelect.html) with the [`likeIgnoreCase()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Field.html#likeIgnoreCase(org.jooq.Field)) predicate. I've added a feature request for this:
[#14958](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14958)

You can easily emulate it yourself:

```kotlin
private fun Condition.andProjectIn(projects: Collection<String>): Condition = 
    when {
        projects.isNotEmpty() -> this.and(DSL.or(
            projects.map { p -> FOO.PROJECT_NAME.likeIgnoreCase(p) }.toList()
        ))
        else -> this
    }
```